# Why main loop stops at last iteration

Tags: c++

my program should accept input from:
3
UUUDU
DDD
UU

the output should be
3
0
2

but it stops at 0

```
int t;
cin >> t;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    string s;
    vector<int> n;
    int m;
    cin>>s;
    for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
        if( s.at(j) =='U' ) {
         m++; 
        }
        else { 
            n.push_back(m); 
            m=0; 
        }
    }
    if(n.size()>0){
        sort(n.begin(),n.end());
    }
    cout<<n[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: the second loop does not enter on last iteration of main loop

Comment: For future posts, please explain why the expected output should be what it is. So the first item input is the number of strings to follow, the remaining inputs are those strings, and the function's job is to print how many letter U's appear in each input.

Comment: @jarmod yes, but last string is the problem

Comment: See `std::string` and `std::getline`.

Comment: @Jee What is teh code trying to do? To count the letter 'U' in each string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn't read `n[0]` when `n` has no elements.

To avoid the error, the part

```cpp
if(n.size()>0){
    sort(n.begin(),n.end());
}
cout<<n[0]<<endl;
```

should be

```cpp
if(n.size()>0){
    sort(n.begin(),n.end());
    cout<<n[0]<<endl;
}
else {
    cout<<0<<endl;
}
```

Also there are other logical errors:

- The variable `m` is used without initialization.
- The final value of `m` (corresponds to the final chunk of `U`) is not pushed.
- To get the maximum value, the last (not first) element should be readed after sorting.

Fixing these errors, your program will be:

```cpp
int t;
cin >> t;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    string s;
    vector<int> n;
    int m=0; // initialize m
    cin>>s;
    for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
        if( s.at(j) =='U' ) {
         m++; 
        }
        else { 
            n.push_back(m); 
            m=0; 
        }
    }
    if(m>0){
        n.push_back(m); // push the final value of m
    }
    if(n.size()>0){
        sort(n.begin(),n.end());
        cout<<n[n.size()-1]<<endl; // read the last element
    }
    else{
        cout<<0<<endl;
    }
}
```